# How to display Icon for an Entry in Linechart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I tried to add icon in a specific position in my LineChart by adding the icon in the Entry constructor :
`Entry(x, y, drawable)`

I configured my LineChart like this :

```
lineChart.also {
        it.setPinchZoom(false)
        it.setTouchEnabled(false)
        it.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
        it.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        it.xAxis.isEnabled = false
        it.description.isEnabled = false
        it.legend.isEnabled = false
        it.isDragEnabled = false
        it.setScaleEnabled(false)
        it.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        it.setDrawGridBackground(false)
       it.setDrawMarkers(false)
        it.isHighlightPerTapEnabled = false
        it.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
    }
```

And my LineDataSet :

```
val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "Unused label").also {
            it.color = lineColor
            it.setDrawValues(false)
            it.setDrawFilled(true)
            it.fillColor = fillColor
            it.setDrawCircleHole(false)
            it.setDrawCircles(false)
            it.lineWidth = 1.5f
            it.isHighlightEnabled = false
            it.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)
        }
```

The LineChart is displayed well but not the entry's icon.

Did I missed something ?

Regards,

Comment: I found the issue origin. This is because I have more than 100 values to display in the x-axis.

Comment: The solution is to add : it.setMaxVisibleValueCount(valueList.size+1)